# Does the function declaration order matter in a header file?

Tags: c++, c++11, declaration

I wonder if the declaration order of a function in a header has an importance.

Let's imagine : I've got two projects that use the same header definition, and the header had to be copied for some obscure reason. And these headers are not the same in terms of declaration function order.

So the header for my first project would be :

```
class A {
  someFunctionA();
  someFunctionB();
}
```

and the header in the second project :

```
class A {
  someFunctionB();
  someFunctionA();
}
```

And now what will happen if I use the implementation created in the first project in my second project (like a dynamic library or whatever) ?

I'm aware that I should use the same header definition for both project, I was just wondering if the compiler will use some sort of stack for the functions or will reorder them.

Comment: The order of member function declarations in classes are irrelevant. Member variables on the other hand, there the order matters.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What about virtual functions?

Comment: @DyP Ah, *virtual* functions, that's another matter yes. :) There the order might matter as otherwise there will be two different virtual function tables.

Comment: The fact is that the first project is managed by another team and modifications can take longer than expected whereas we need the modifications to be made quickly. So we modify temporarily the files but when the modifications are effectively done one the first project that kind of differences can be seen. @Joachim Pileborg yes virtual functions are also part of the problem and i forgot to mention them.

Comment: Don't you need that other team's *implementation* as well?  If this is just a hack to get your code to compile then it doesn't matter, it only goes wrong at runtime.

Comment: Well what you immediately need are return types for your functions.

Comment: @Hans Passant We make our own implementation as we can also manipulate other implementations that we don't know. And I do have to run to test, so there is the problem. I know there is project management issues which appears because of a rather complex structure in the company that I've no hands on. So, the question was purely technical. But sure, the real origin is causing all of this troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you're sharing the same header file, you can still come up against this issue with versioning. For example, your project might have been compiled against version 1 of the dynamic library. You then ship version 2 of the library without recompiling your project. In that situation, you need to ensure the library does not break binary compatibility.

A good list of what can and can't be done in maintaining binary compatibility is here: http://techbase.kde.org/Policies/Binary_Compatibility_Issues_With_C++#The_Do.27s_and_Don.27ts

To answer your question, you can re-order non-virtual functions but not member variables or virtuals.

Answer (score 9):

Strictly speaking, you have undefined behaviour unless both class definitions are identical (defined as consisting of the same sequence of tokens after preprocessing).

In practice, there probably won't be any issues as long as the memory layout of both classes remains the same. Adding, removing or reordering non-virtual member functions won't affect the layout. Doing that to base classes, data members or virtual member functions will affect the layout, and could lead to horrendously inscrutable bugs.

Since it's impossible to prevent incompatible changes, I'd strongly advise you not to do this. Either find a way to share the same class definition between projects, or fully branch it and maintain each branch separately.

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration order **matters** especially if the **function declaration has default arguments**.

**For example** in the below function declaration if you change the declaration order then the compile gives you - missing default parameter error. Reason is compiler allows you to separate the function declaration with default argument with in the same scope but it should be in order from **RIGHT to LEFT** (default arguments) and from **TOP to BOTTOM**(order of function declaration default argument).

```
//declaration
void function(char const *msg, bool three, bool two, bool one = false);
//void function(char const *msg, bool three = true, bool two, bool one); //Error 
void function(char const *msg, bool three, bool two = true, bool one); // OK
void function(char const *msg, bool three = true, bool two, bool one); // OK

int main() {
    function("Using only one Default Argument", false, true);
    function("Using Two Default Arguments", false);
    function("Using Three Default Arguments");
    return 0;
}

//definition
void function(char const *msg, bool three, bool two, bool one ) {
    std::cout<<msg<<" "<<three<<" "<<two<<" "<<one<<std::endl;
}
```